# Can not bootstrap my corda node which cannot bind its public ip address

Tags: corda

I have deployed a node on a cloud server which has a public  ip address (but I cannot use ifconfig command to find the public ip interface )...I just get some error while I try to run the node... the network map server is on the other server

[this picture show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs51Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that a process is already bound to one of the ports the node is attempting to use.

You need to kill this process first. If it's a Java process, try `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete` on Windows, or `killall java -9` on Mac.